# Replace keywords from text using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I replace values from a string like that:

```
// "Hello ##name##, today is ##date##"
```

It's possible like that:

```js
    var string = "Hello ##name##, today is ##date##"
    console.log(string.replace('##name##', 'John Doe'));
```

But how replace the `##date##`too, and  build the string again?

Comment: `string.replace('##name##', 'John Doe').replace('##date##', new Date())` and note `replace()` will return new string

Comment: You can use a regex.

Comment: I suggest using JavaScript Templating Engines eg mustache.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use a regex and pass a function as a second argument:

```js
var string = "Hello ##name##, today is ##date##";
const map = {name: 'Foo', date: 'bar'};

console.log(string.replace(/##(\w+)##/g, (_,m) => map[m]));
```